# Dynamically add values to resource string-array in Android

Tags: android, arrays, android-resources

Is there a way to dynamically add values to an Android resource `string-array`?

E.g.:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="titles">
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: What is your use case? You could simply build the string array list in code and pass it where needed.

Comment: @bond I want to store some data, and I'm wondering if there's an easier way such as writing to a resource xml file rather than using a database

Comment: if it is a small list, you could save it in shared preferences. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html, See, putStringSet() method. Also another alternative would be to use something like Realm db if you rather save objects. www.realm.io

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to dynamically add values to an Android resource string-array?

No, because resources are read-only at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! you can create a static array of strings in Android but dynamically adding values to an Android resource is not yet possible.
It turns out that it’s easy to create and use a static array of strings in Android. Of course, you can do this in Java code, as I describe in my Java string array tutorial, but for Android, I’m talking about doing this in XML.

In short, this is how you define a static string array in an Android XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="my_books">
        <item>Scala Cookbook</item>
        <item>Play Framework Recipes</item>
        <item>How I Sold My Business: A Personal Diary</item>
        <item>A Survival Guide for New Consultants</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Then inside an Activity, Fragment, or other Java class, you can create a string array in Java from that XML like this:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] myBooks = res.getStringArray(R.array.my_books);
```